# Tradingview Pine Script - Set commission_value dynamically in code

Tags: pine-script

I am having a CFD Account where the fee is 1.5 Pips per winning trade.

For example:

Account Balance: 2000€ /
Percentage per trade: 1% ==> 20€ per trade

Case 1:
Stop Loss is set to 10 Pips =>
Fee = 20€ / 10 Pips * 1.5 Pips = 3€

Case 2:
Stop Loss is set to 8 Pips =>
Fee = 20€ / 8 Pips * 1.5 Pips = 3.75€

In case that the SL is hit, then the 20€ from the example above are deducted.

I know that in the pine script strategy a fixed commission per trade can be entered in the function call by

```
commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order, commission_value=2.00
```

However, this does not match with the case mentioned above.

Is there any way in pine script to set the `commission_value` dynamically in the `strategy.entry` or `strategy.exit` calls?

I searched already in many forums, but could not find any way how to achieve the result.

Comment: Does anyone know another possibility instead of doing the analysis in Excel or something as vitruvius suggested?

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.

What you can do is, set the commission value to 0, but calculate the commission yourself. Then diplay this in a table together with some other stats.

Comment: hm this is too bad. It would be great if Tradingview let people set their own custom commission.